# How do I update Python to version 3?

Tags: python, raspbian-wheezy

Is there any way to update Python on the Raspberry Pi (Wheezy) to [Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/download/)?

Comment: You probably don't want to change the _default_. Any system software that uses Python will probably break. You could add an alias for your account. Is typing python3 instead of python really so hard?

Comment: Do not change the default version unless you really need to, use virtualenv to create 'sanboxed' Python environments. You can install Python 3 into one of them without affecting any other projects that way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install Python 3 easily:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

**However**: I wouldn't recommend settting this as the *default* version of Python.

If you're not already, starting using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), a tool for creating 'sandboxed' Python environments. Virtualenv will let you install multiple versions of Python without them conflicting with each other.

Installation is easy:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

and creating a *virtual environment* in a folder is easy too:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 FOLDER
```

The -p flag tells you which version of Python to use.
Then if you go into that folder:

```
$ cd FOLDER
```

you'll notice files like so:

```
$ ls
bin include lib
```

To **activate** this virtualenv type:

```
$ . bin/activate
```

The terminal line with change like so:

```
(FOLDER)$root@raspiberrypi: $
```

or something similar. The(FOLDER) part at the front tells you you're using the virtualenv.

To stop using that virtualenv just type:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer? According to [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10240/34985) there is no 3.3 version available for Wheezy.

Comment: I wanted to ask if installing python3 with apt-get will also make it default or not