# Upgrade from Python 2.7 to 3.3,x

Tags: python

How do I uninstall Python 2.7 and install the latest Python 3.3.x?
Tried using "upgrade" but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the 3.x version you want by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-3.2
```

Which will install version 3.2 of python side-by-side with version 2.7.

I was doing this previously and I recall that you then need to specifically specify the version of python you want to run such as `python3.2`.

According to http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3.3, there isn't a version of python 3.3 available for wheezy

I also don't see a python3.3 in the Raspbian package list located at [this link](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages) courtesy of [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/does-raspbians-repository-have-a-browsable-package-list#answer-1180).

[Here's](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=49023&p=382172#p382172) something from the Raspberry Pi forum that shows how to download and compile Python 3.3.2 directly on the Pi.  This doesn't say how long it takes to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I use `testing` in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi
```

This gives you a good balance between stability and up-to-dateness (I have never had problems with `testing` on any of my debian boxes, RPi or others).

As example, this would provide you, as of Oct 2015, Python 3.4 (while the version in stable is 3.2).